# How can I hide non-mailing list groups in receipts?

Tags: civimail, email, groups, receipts, templates

At the moment, when someone signs up for a membership or makes a contribution, the receipt returns a list of their newsletter subscription groups AND non-mailing lists group assignments.

How can I hide the non-mailing lists group assignments from the receipt?

Comment: I take it the Profile they fill in on your form has the  Group(s) profile field in it? Otherwise I don't get the answer, and only figured this by following Jon's links

Answer (score 1):

In CiviCRM 4.6+, this only happens if the user receiving the receipt has a user account, and that account has the "View All Contacts" permission.  See [CRM-16433](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16433?focusedCommentId=73947&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-73947) for details.